# Error in the syntax of the SQL insert query using variables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

While trying to insert a record in the sql table I am using 10 variables for 10 columns in the table, but as when I run the query it throws an error. I have tried looking if there is any typo in my code but can't find any:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','2019','12','3','10660','2018-12-11','UTC',''{"sleepIQScore": {"min": 0, "max"' at line 1

My code is:

```
public void insertDataTable1() throws SQLException {
    connection = new MyConnection().getConnection();
    Random random = new Random();
    String timeZone = "UTC";
    String dummyJson = "'{\"sleepIQScore\": {\"min\": 0, \"max\": 0, \"sum\": 0, \"count\": 0}}')";
    int longestSessionDuration = 1000 + random.nextInt(9999), bamUserID = 1000000 + random.nextInt(9999999);
    int year = 2019, month = 12, sleepSessionCount =3;
    java.sql.Date longestSessionStart = new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());

    String sql = "INSERT INTO aggregates_all_time(bam_user,year,month,sleep_session_count," +
            "longest_session_total_duration,longest_session_start,timezone, current_stats, second_longest_session_stats, prior_stats)"
            + "VALUES ("+bamUserID+"','"+year+"','"+month+"','"+sleepSessionCount+"','"+longestSessionDuration+"','" +
            ""+longestSessionStart+"','"+timeZone+"','"+dummyJson+" ','"+dummyJson+"','"+dummyJson+")";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(i + " Row/s inserted");

}
```

Comment: Print the string from "sql" variable and share it

Comment: In `"VALUES ("+bamUserID+"','"` you can probably remove the first single quote

Comment: This is not how you are supposed to use prepared statements. Do not concatenate values into a query string. It is unsafe and/or leads to bugs like your question. Use parameters instead.

Comment: Avoid concatenating strings. Use a PreparedStatement instead. Your code is not safe agains SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

You should never concatenate values into a query string like this. It is unsafe because it opens your application to SQL injection which is one of the major causes of security issues. In addition, it leads to bugs like your question because of missing quotes, etc.

However, the solution is not to add those missing quotes, because that still leaves you open to SQL injection risks. Instead, you need to use parameters and set the values for those parameters before execution.

A reduced example based on the query in your question:

```
try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO aggregates_all_time(bam_user, year, month, ..) values (?, ?, ?, ..)")) {
    preparedStatement.setInt(bamUserID);
    preparedStatement.setInt(year);
    preparedStatement.setInt(month);
    // other values

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

See also [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) in the JDBC tutorial.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark.